# How can I rewrite my code using only read(2) and write(2)?

Tags: c, linux

I have to make a C program that acts similar to the Linux head command. Currently, I have the basic part of it implemented by printing a certain number of lines of a text file. The problem is it works fine with fgets() and fopen() but I'm not allowed to use these. When I try changing it to read() and open() It just prints the whole file rather than just the specific number of lines.

```
#define BUFFSIZE 10000
int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen(argv[3], "r");

  char buffer[BUFFSIZE];
  char *input = argv[1];
  //printf("%s", input);
  int number = atoi(argv[2]);

  int n;
  while (fgets(buffer, BUFSIZE,fp) != NULL) {
       printf("%s", buffer);
       n++;
       if (n > number-1) break;

  }
```

}

Comment: `fgets` is reading a single line (maximum). So if you want to emulate it with `read`, you will need to read character by character till a newline is read.

Comment: You should be able to change it to use `open`, `read`, `write`, and `close`.  The `read` system call has no support for line breaks, so you'll have to do that yourself.  You will probably want to read the data into your `buffer` and then scan for the newline characters yourself.  I recommend that you try this and then add your code to the quesiton and details about why it doesn't work.  There are lots of edge cases to worry about so the code is not going to be very short or elegant.

Comment: So, you got your program working using standard C functions are you are now told that you can't use those and must use a platform specific low level API? ... but ... why?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Not the weirdest constraint I've encountered in HW assignments :D

Comment: @EugeneSh. :-) Ah yes, homework. I often miss to identify those questions still ...